# Google Now app force closes/crashes immediately upon launch

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, crashes, google-now, force-close, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm running rooted stock Android 4.4.2 on an AT&T Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900A). No problems with any other Gapps or apps in general. I have tried flashing older versions, but that didn't help. The problem remains whether it is installed as a regular user app or a privileged app. I have also tried running a permissions fixer on it.

As soon as I tap the icon the app displays for a few seconds and closes. If I erase the cache and app data it will run once correctly, but the problem returns after the account settings and whatnot are reinstalled.

Any help would be appreciated

```
01-12 11:57:19.576 I/MultiDex(24767): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
01-12 11:57:19.576 I/MultiDex(24767): install
01-12 11:57:19.576 I/MultiDex(24767): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-1.apk, false)
01-12 11:57:19.586 I/MultiDex(24767): loading existing secondary dex files
01-12 11:57:19.586 I/MultiDex(24767): load found 2 secondary dex files
01-12 11:57:19.586 I/MultiDex(24767): install done
01-12 11:57:19.596 I/SearchInitializer(24767): Initialized process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
01-12 11:57:19.606 W/ApplicationPackageManager(24767): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-12 11:57:19.616 E/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find class 'android.content.pm.LauncherApps', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.y.b.a.j
01-12 11:57:19.616 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 201 (Landroid/content/pm/LauncherApps;) in Lcom/google/android/apps/gsa/shared/y/b/a;
01-12 11:57:19.616 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0046
01-12 11:57:19.656 D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(908): ContainerId: 0
01-12 11:57:19.656 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2065): refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
01-12 11:57:19.666 W/ActivityManager(908): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
01-12 11:57:19.666 D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(2065): checkOverflow(360), More:false, Req:false Child:1
01-12 11:57:19.676 W/ContextImpl(908): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1469 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked:1002 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked:1940 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeTopActivitiesLocked:3076 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeTopActivitiesLocked:3054 
01-12 11:57:19.686 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(908): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/pause]
01-12 11:57:19.696 V/WindowOrientationListener(908): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
01-12 11:57:19.696 V/WindowOrientationListener(908): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
01-12 11:57:19.696 V/WindowOrientationListener(908): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
01-12 11:57:19.696 V/WindowOrientationListener(908): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: -1
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/Launcher(2965): onStop, Launcher: 1163129296
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/Launcher.HomeView(2965): onStop
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/AbsListView(2965): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/AbsListView(2965): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/AbsListView(2965): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/AbsListView(2965): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/SurfaceWidgetClient$ISurfaceWidgetStub(15032): [123491/1] Surface widget visibility changed visibility = false on instance = 1
01-12 11:57:19.696 D/SurfaceWidgetView(2965): destroyHardwareResources():1135437944
01-12 11:57:19.696 V/WindowManager(908): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false
01-12 11:57:19.706 W/ContextImpl(908): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1469 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked:1156 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked:1299 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked:2257 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeTopActivitiesLocked:3076 
01-12 11:57:19.736 I/com.sec.att.apo.ApoService(2821): On foreground activity changed : 2965,10009,false
01-12 11:57:19.736 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method com.google.android.apps.gsa.searchnow.SearchNowActivity.finishAndRemoveTask, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.searchnow.SearchNowActivity.Ai
01-12 11:57:19.736 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 39376: Lcom/google/android/apps/gsa/searchnow/SearchNowActivity;.finishAndRemoveTask ()V
01-12 11:57:19.736 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
01-12 11:57:19.736 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(908): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/create]
01-12 11:57:19.736 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2065): onReceive() - RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION, WIFI_STATE, NETWORK_STATE
01-12 11:57:19.746 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.app.Activity.releaseInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.ui.i.releaseInstance
01-12 11:57:19.746 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/app/Activity;.releaseInstance ()Z
01-12 11:57:19.746 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-12 11:57:19.746 W/ApplicationPackageManager(24767): getCSCPackageItemText()
01-12 11:57:19.756 D/Launcher(2965): onTrimMemory. Level: 20
01-12 11:57:19.796 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.shared.ui.j.setInsets
01-12 11:57:19.796 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 891: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-12 11:57:19.796 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003e
01-12 11:57:19.796 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.shared.ui.j.setInsets
01-12 11:57:19.796 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 891: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-12 11:57:19.796 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0053
01-12 11:57:19.796 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.view.View.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.ui.drawer.AccountNavigationDrawerLayout.akf
01-12 11:57:19.796 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13155: Landroid/view/View;.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener (Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V
01-12 11:57:19.796 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x007b
01-12 11:57:19.806 I/dalvikvm(24767): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/people/accountswitcherview/k; interface 2005 'Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;'
01-12 11:57:19.806 W/dalvikvm(24767): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/people/accountswitcherview/k;' failed
01-12 11:57:19.806 E/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.people.accountswitcherview.k', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.ui.drawer.AccountNavigationDrawerLayout.akf
01-12 11:57:19.806 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 12126 (Lcom/google/android/gms/people/accountswitcherview/k;) in Lcom/google/android/apps/gsa/shared/ui/drawer/AccountNavigationDrawerLayout;
01-12 11:57:19.806 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0088
01-12 11:57:19.806 I/dalvikvm(24767): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/people/accountswitcherview/k; interface 2005 'Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;'
01-12 11:57:19.806 W/dalvikvm(24767): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/people/accountswitcherview/k;' failed
01-12 11:57:19.806 D/dalvikvm(24767): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xcd52 at 0x8a in Lcom/google/android/apps/gsa/shared/ui/drawer/AccountNavigationDrawerLayout;.akf
01-12 11:57:19.826 D/dalvikvm(12902): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2095K, 23% free 26394K/34056K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 60ms
01-12 11:57:19.826 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5339 (ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD) in Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo$AccessibilityAction;
01-12 11:57:19.826 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0037
01-12 11:57:19.826 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5341 (ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD) in Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo$AccessibilityAction;
01-12 11:57:19.826 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x004d
01-12 11:57:19.836 W/EDMNativeHelper(256): EDMNativeHelperService is published
01-12 11:57:19.856 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.ui.d.setTarget
01-12 11:57:19.856 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13192: Landroid/view/ViewAnimationUtils;.createCircularReveal (Landroid/view/View;IIFF)Landroid/animation/Animator;
01-12 11:57:19.856 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0053
01-12 11:57:19.906 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.permissions.a.a
01-12 11:57:19.906 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
01-12 11:57:19.906 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002d
01-12 11:57:19.916 I/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.f.a.d
01-12 11:57:19.916 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 876: Landroid/content/Context;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
01-12 11:57:19.916 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
01-12 11:57:19.936 E/dalvikvm(24767): Could not find class 'android.content.pm.LauncherApps', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.shared.multiuser.l.connect
01-12 11:57:19.936 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 201 (Landroid/content/pm/LauncherApps;) in Lcom/google/android/apps/gsa/search/shared/multiuser/l;
01-12 11:57:19.936 D/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0085
01-12 11:57:19.936 D/dalvikvm(24767): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
01-12 11:57:19.936 W/dalvikvm(24767): VFY: unable to resolve static field 236 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
```

Comment: I'm not an expert at reading logcats but it looks like an error might be happening when it initializes the microphone. Though why is the mic being initialized when I'm just launching the app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > Apps > Click on Google Search. Clear cache / Clear Data. See if that helps.

If not, then check the play store for updates to the Google app.

If problem persists, then uninstall Google now using titanium backup or some other app of your preference and reinstall from play store.

Comment: If you re-read my question I already tried those things. And I've tried installing it as a privileged app. And I've tried earlier versions.

Comment: Since you are rooted, try flashing the gapps package again and wiping dalvik cache

Comment: You suggest flashing an entire gapps package? Is that necessary when only one Gapp is having issues? I'm not sure where to find a gapps zip compatible with KitKat. I tried flashing an older version of the app designed for KK but the same behavior persists. Also I have to use FlashFire to flash because this model has a locked down bootloader. It's rather finicky sometimes.

Comment: @Jesse you can get the gapps from opengapps.org Flashing the gapps package is necessary because it contains all the dependencies needed by the individual apps.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. In my case its the cards that were causing it. I turned off the feed and deleted cards preferences and it works ok.